# How do i get the position of the nodes that are rebroadcasting the packet in veins/Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, veins

By using wsm->getSenderPos i could get the position of the node that has generated the message. But when some other node has rebroadcasted the message the senderposition remains the same of the node generating the message. Is there any way i can get the position of the node that has rebroadcasted the message at the reciever side.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to Veins 4.4, [the sample `WaveShortMessage` message type contained a field `senderPos`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg#L50) that could be used by applications to store/retrieve positions. The [sample `BaseWaveApplLayer::prepareWSM` application did this](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L77) to allow a user to easily visualize how far a message has traveled.

There is no special significance to the contents of this field. Feel free to have your application use this message field to store a new position with every hop (by calling the `setSenderPos` method).